# Add method works, Delete / remove does not C# REST API

Tags: c#, .net, json, rest, firebase-realtime-database

Having troubles getting my remove method to work. 
I'm trying to get it so I can remove an item from an order using Postman.
Adding works just fine, removing doesn't. I keep trying to google solutions but keep finding the wrong things. I need to make sure I remove the item based on the lineNumber and OrderID so I don't remove the same lineNumber across all orders.

The following is my add method followed by my current remove method. I have a feeling it's probably something I just haven't learned yet that would normally be obvious?

```
           public async Task<short> AddAsync(int orderID, OrderItemDTO item)
    {
        if (item.LineNumber != 0)
        {
            throw new ValidationException("LineNumber is generated and cannot be specified");
        }

        short lineNumber = (short)(_db.OrderItems.Where(oi => oi.OrderID == orderID).Max(oi => oi.LineNumber) + 1);

        _db.OrderItems.Add(new OrderItem()
        {   
            Quantity = item.Quantity,
            OrderID = orderID,
            LineNumber = lineNumber,
            Price = item.Price,
            ProductID = item.ProductID,
            StudentPersonID = item.StudentPersonID
        });

        await _db.SaveChangesAsync();

        return lineNumber;
    }


    public async Task<short> RemoveAsync(int orderID, OrderItemDTO item)
    {
        if (item.LineNumber != 0)
        {
            throw new ValidationException("LineNumber is generated and cannot be specified");
        }

        short lineNumber = (short)(_db.OrderItems.Where(oi => oi.OrderID == orderID).Max(oi => oi.LineNumber));

        _db.OrderItems.Remove(new OrderItem()
        {

            OrderID = orderID,
            LineNumber = lineNumber,

        });


        await _db.SaveChangesAsync();

        return lineNumber;
    }
```

Comment: The problem is, you didn't list what do you see, what error do you get if any? Do you hit your action at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to me that, you are missing `[HttpPost]` and `[HttpDelete]` above your methods.

Please see the reference [Microsoft Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/older-versions/creating-a-web-api-that-supports-crud-operations)

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<short> AddAsync(int orderID, OrderItemDTO item)

[HttpDelete]
public async Task<short> RemoveAsync(int orderID, OrderItemDTO item)
```

Updated 1:

```
public async Task<short> RemoveAsync(int orderID, OrderItemDTO item)
    {
        if (item.LineNumber != 0)
        {
            throw new ValidationException("LineNumber is generated and cannot be specified");
        }

        var objToDelete = _db.OrderItems.Where(oi => oi.OrderID == orderID && oi.LineNumber == item.LineNumber);

        _db.OrderItems.Remove(objToDelete);    

        await _db.SaveChangesAsync();

        return xxx ;  //replace what you want to return
    }
```

Updated 2:

This line of code is never going to remove an object from the EF Entity because you created and passed the new object to the Remove method.  EF will not be able to find the object to remove.

```
_db.OrderItems.Remove(new OrderItem()
        {
            OrderID = orderID,
            LineNumber = lineNumber
        });
```

Instead of that, firstly, you need to get the object which you want to remove from the Entity.  Then pass that object.  It can be done in one line but, I will write it in 2 lines for the clarity.

```
short lineNumber = (short)(_db.OrderItems.Where(oi => oi.OrderID == orderID).Max(oi => oi.LineNumber));

// this will get the object to delete due to your criteria
var objToDelete = _db.OrderItems.Where(oi => oi.OrderID == orderID && oi.LineNumber == lineNumber );

_db.OrderItems.Remove(objToDelete);

await _db.SaveChangesAsync();

return lineNumber;
```

Comment: Adding works just fine, I've used Postman and it adds an item to the order just fine, I don't believe it would be that, I've already seen the reference page. There's probably an error elsewhere as well or I'm writing the remove incorrectly.

Comment: What error or result do you get back from Remove method?

Comment: I do not get any error in visual studio, I get one on Postman when I run a delete for order 3 line 4, "ExceptionMessage": "LineNumber is generated and cannot be specified",
  "ExceptionType": "System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationException",

Comment: The update you posted does not work as LineNumber was never made in the delete method. I'm debugging an application someone else made, it uses an SQL database to store the information. I thought if I did the opposite of the add function I should be able to delete items from orders.

Comment: @dsantrat *"I do not get any error in visual studio"* - did you setup debugger to throw exceptions?

Comment: @T.S It's not set to ignore any errors all settings are on the default settings from install. Pretty new to VS however, it's given plenty of errors for everything else

Answer (score 0):

I was removing from the database incorrectly and then attempting to remove it again after it had already been removed. Changed the code to remove it after the object was created from the input.